# libpng error: Not a PNG file Error Showing In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I just Imported a project from `Eclipe to Android Studio`. Just a plain and simple project. But the project folder is showing one error .

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective? I am new in Android-studio .Does any guys meet this issue?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is `Logcat` :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Failed to run command:
    /home/amiya/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt s -i /home/amiya/vola/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/call.png -o /home/amiya/vola/app/build/res/all/debug/drawable-mdpi/call.png
  Error Code:
    42
  Output:
    libpng error: Not a PNG file
```

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
 apply plugin: 'android'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }



}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/livesdk.jar')
}
```

I am not using this file anywhere in my project with that name !! There are many other png files in my project though.

Comment: Check for that png image in your drawable folder..

Comment: Same question, same comment: Check if the mentioned file call.png exists and if it is a valid PNG file. E.g. open it with an hex editor and verify that it has the "PNG" in the first bytes.

Comment: Also look for IHDR within the first 16 bytes.  Chances are the file contains "CgBI" where "IHDR" is supposed to be.

Comment: I am having same error but it is not showing any file name which is corrupted.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should follow below steps.

1. ***Cut-paste the image on my desktop***.
2. ***Opened it in an editor saved it as png. without renaming the file
   name***.
3. ***Copy-pasted the `.png` image into the drawable folder***.

You can use **`cruncherEnabled`**.

> Returns true if the PNGs should be crunched, false otherwise.

```
android 
{ 
   aaptOptions
   {
   cruncherEnabled = false
   } 
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: In my case, I am not getting which PNG file has this problem. So I am not able to apply your solutions!

Comment: @BharatDodeja Okay .Whats your logcat returns ?

Comment: AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
:aIDEConsumerOff:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':aIDEConsumerOff:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: @BharatDodeja I assume images are corrupted

Comment: but my question is which image? :)

Comment: @BharatDodeja I did't get this type of `Error`  yet .Okay . I will check on #SO . #IDE Not showing which ?

Comment: Finally, I have found which drawables were not actual PNG by comparing res folder with res of my backup copy of working project. Their file sizes was different. :)

Comment: @BharatDodeja Did you fixed yet ?

Comment: I set this in `android/build.gradle` and I was able to skip the 3 first steps. thanks!

Answer (score 31):

Try this in build.gradle

```
android {
    ....
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: useNewCruncher = false

Comment: what is the difference between `useNewCruncher` and `cruncherEnabled` ?

Answer (score 26):

Try run command

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" | xargs -L 1 -I{} file  -I {} | grep -v 'image/png; charset=binary$'
```

in your root project directory, it will show you all files that have **.png** extension, but are not pngs.
Then you can resave them as png in some image editor.
Before running this command clean project, to speed up the process.

Comment: Prints "file: invalid option -- 'I'" for me.

Answer (score 20):

It might be because of renaming problem of the Image just cut the images and paste any where in the system and open each with the respective editor and save as the same but of **`PNG`** format 
and then **copy and paste** again to drawable folders. It works for me

**[AND PLEASE LOOK AT THE ISSUE WHICH I SUBMITTED TO THE ANDROID STUDIO TEAM](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74081)**

Hope it will help you all .

Comment: @MSI just ckeck Your Format of image by opening it into an image editor  say Paint in windows and in linux image viewer and save check their format instead of looking at their extension right?

Comment: @MSI I have edited my Answer Please do look at the issue link It will Solve Your Problem and if it helps don't forget to vote me up thanx

Comment: thanks Spry. just use windows edit function to re-save it as png. and that works :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Mac OS, follow the steps below to get a png

1. Open image in preview
2. Go to file -> Export
3. Set format as png
4. Click on save

This will give you a valid png

Mere renaming or changing extension won't work in Mac OS.

Answer (score 2):

"PNG" in the error is clearly written in caps. So you need to see that the image has .PNG extension (in Capital).

Step 1: Open the image in **Paint**.

Step 2: Save the image **Save as .PNG** shown as below
[Click here to see how to save the image in PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiQAM.png)

Step 3: Refresh your project

Step 4: You should see like this -> [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEk0G.png)

Please do reply if the issue is still not resolved

Answer (score 0):

As for me, what was happening is that I cloned the repository on Windows, and those PNG files were symlinks in Linux/Mac, but on Windows they were just invalid files. Once I did proper copies of the files instead of being symlinks, the build worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use another **png** files. It seems something wrong with ***png's metadata***. I had the same issue. Then I used some other **png** files and it fixed my issue.