# Android Studio project import issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I've recently played with Vitamio and then I've imported a different project, however, when trying to build it, the following output was generated:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources]
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
libpng error: Not a PNG file
libpng error: Not a PNG file
Error:Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe s -i W:\VitamioBundle-master\playstream-master\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\tt.png -o W:\VitamioBundle-master\playstream-master\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\tt.png
Error Code:
    42
Output:
    libpng error: Not a PNG file
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe s -i W:\VitamioBundle-master\playstream-master\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\tt.png -o W:\VitamioBundle-master\playstream-master\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\tt.png
Error Code:
    42
Output:
    libpng error: Not a PNG file
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.26 secs
libpng error: Not a PNG file
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

It's not clear to me as to why this happen, this project is completely unrelated to Vitamio in any way, it's in it's own folder and all, the only thing in common is the root drive W:\ in this case.

The question is: Why this happen?

Note: that I'm not very familiar with Android Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366222/libpng-error-not-a-png-file-error-showing-in-android-studio

Comment: @Nicks unless I'm missing something, it doesn't seem to be a duplicate, in my situation, it's complaining about the png file, yet, it's not clear why the folder is "W:\VitamioBundle-master\playstream-master\" in stead of "W:\playstream-master\", I've used "Import Project"

Comment: Just wondering, were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Nicks no, I just gave up on it, android dev tools are too immature for my taste... lost too much time for basic stuff, moved focus on iOS.