# Android studio How to resolve Error in png files of library added

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, android-build

I have no Idea what is happening, last time when I finished my app I build its release apk and all was working just fine as expected but now today when I tried to make that pproject again and to make another apk I am getting the following error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > Crunching Cruncher common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light.9.png failed, see logs

I have no idea how to resolve it I have serached and found restarting Android studio and clean the project would remove it , doing this many times has no effect on this error. I have even restarted my machine but the condition of error in same.

In the logs I have seen that this png file is from the library I added , so just for testing I removed that library and tried to build then it started to give me same error with different png file name in other library. So how to fix this issue ?

My Questions are :
How can this issue be Solved ?
Have some one faced this problem too ?
Is this problem has been reported to google ?
Why in android we do not have any stable platform for development as IOS have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove "builds" folders and do rebuild. But soon, the whole thing in a long file name. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25209204/2413972). By the way, you looked logs? [Maybe this is not the PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23366222/2413972)? You have not sent the log and did not specify the version Gradle.

Believe me, iOS developers have own problems.

Comment: I did ios development too , and fund that a more reliabe dude  :)  well let me include and update my question

Comment: Luck is a fickle thing. I do not know what to add to my answer.

Comment: Your link worked like a charm , so windows Sucks too ;)

Comment: I hope that you decide your problem with Gradle.