# android AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file

Tags: android

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :RongPush:generateDebugSources, :RongPush:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:RongPush:clean
:RongPush:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:RongPush:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:RongPush:checkDebugManifest
:RongPush:prepareDebugDependencies
:RongPush:compileDebugAidl
:RongPush:compileDebugRenderscript
:RongPush:generateDebugBuildConfig
:RongPush:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:RongPush:mergeDebugAssets
:RongPush:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:RongPush:generateDebugResources
:RongPush:mergeDebugResources
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
:RongPush:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':RongPush:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.421 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366222/libpng-error-not-a-png-file-error-showing-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Complete those steps and solve your problem:**

1) Cut-paste the image on your desktop.

2) Opened it in an editor saved it as png. without renaming the file name.

3) Copy-pasted the .png image into the drawable folder.