# Getting error when I try to put background in my android program

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle

I try to put any background in my android program like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mypic"
    tools:context="com.mm.openreg.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/S1"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
```

and I got this error:

> AAPT err(Facade for 972607565): D:\MyAndroid_Prog\MyAndroidProgram\OpenReg\app\src\main\res\drawable\savea.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
>       AAPT err(Facade for 1945943478): libpng error: Not a PNG file
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

I tried everything but still same error when I run my program.

Is there anyone can help?

- I try also png file and small file - but same

This my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mm.openreg"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366222/libpng-error-not-a-png-file-error-showing-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to update build-tools to fix a faulty aapt.

Open sdk manager and install build-tools 23.0.1 and change your build.gradle so that it looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

Comment: i update my question.  i have this update, what i need to do ?

Comment: did you clean your project?