# Issues after updating android support library dependencies

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I updated android support library dependencies in `build.gradle` file then
When I am trying to build project its showing below error:

```
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

It's working fine when I am using old dependencies:

old dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
```

new dependencies:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-alpha1'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
 compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.0.0-alpha1'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.0.0-alpha1'
```

Can anyone help me out from this issue?
Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: hey refer this .hope so it's useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366222/libpng-error-not-a-png-file-error-showing-in-android-studio

Comment: thank for the response @ExceptionLover  do you have any solution for this issue?

Comment: thanks @ashish i tried but its not working for me. showing same error

Comment: it's your image related issue?

Comment: that's i'm not able to get, why because its working for old libraries for new only its giving error.

Answer (score 0):

There is some related issue that makes the problem arise:

1. This is probably related to the image type which is not a png type but renamed as a png one. You can check your image for the type.
2. The project is using an old build project, so try to clean and rebuild your project.
3. As the last resort, you can try `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart..` from Android Studio menu.