# when i add imageview why show error libpng error: Not a PNG file?

Tags: android, png, logcat

when i add imageview on my layout why then show error AAPT err(Facade for 817338050): libpng error: Not a PNG file

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

and i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366222/libpng-error-not-a-png-file-error-showing-in-android-studio) but still didn't work for me.. my file name splashscreen.png

logcat

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileLint
:library:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:library:checkReleaseManifest
:library:prepareReleaseDependencies
:library:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:library:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:library:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:library:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:library:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:library:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:library:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Alpha2Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Alpha2Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2400Alpha2Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72400Alpha2Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Alpha2Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Alpha2Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleMapsAndroidAndroidMapsUtils043Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareEPlaceCopy2CopyLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(Facade for 817338050): libpng error: Not a PNG file
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 16.704 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

and this is my splashscreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cb"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is the splash screen a png image?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366222/libpng-error-not-a-png-file-error-showing-in-android-studio

Comment: @ShashankUdupa yes

Comment: @MiguelBenitez i have write in post, i have tried that but not work for me

Answer (score 0):

You might have made a mistake. Did you change the extension directly?
You have to use something like paint or photoshop to change the extension and not by renaming it.

Comment: i tried that but still not working for me. the original file name is E-Place.png and i open it using photoshop and save as with name splashscreen.png to drawable folder

Comment: The image you had at the first was in which format?

Comment: png. I created the splashscreen using photoshop

Comment: so you saved it as png or after that you renamed the extension

Comment: first i try to change the extension without tools, but after the error i open the original image(before changed) to be splashscreen.png

Comment: so u do one thing, make this image again and save it in the extension you want or if you have the image that you created first, the very original one, then try to use it first

Comment: it's same error :(
i tried to use the last splashscreen (image before i changed, and previous can work normally) but now it be error too :(

Comment: so try and make a new one

Comment: i tried make new one and save with name splashscreen.png, and that have same error...