# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details build gradle issues

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

currently I am using Android Studio 2.1 when I run my App it shows me some error in Message Gradle Build saying the following

```
 Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2221Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(Facade for 114461397): libpng error: Read Error
*Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details*
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 24.87 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I tried cleaning and rebuilding it but it didn't work. The answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa) question didn't work also. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Updated:**
Here is the log output

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.
java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46
)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskEx
ecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExec
uter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.j
ava:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.j
ava:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecute
r.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecute
r.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecut
or.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:
50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter
.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExe
cuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExe
cuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:23
7)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:21
0)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.waitForAll(QueuedCruncher.java:260)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.end(QueuedCruncher.java:280)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:132)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:295)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:405)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:178)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(A
nnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(Annota
tionProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(Ann
otationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(Annota
tionProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.j
ava:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.
java:61)
        ... 57 more
```

Comment: try this answer.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/30450020/3678308

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All problem was a crashed png image in one of my drawable folders. I mean the images which we sometime face in windows photo viewer, like the one below:
[image]

I dropped the image from the folder and all problem got solved.

Answer (score 32):

In the individual apps's build.gradle, section `android {}`, insert :

```
aaptOptions {  
    cruncherEnabled = false  
}
```

[Reference](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65335)

Comment: Thanks lot @shadyagoneinsane , you saved me lot .

Comment: thanks so much! I've imported a project from Eclipse to ANdroid Studio and had this error "Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details" .

Comment: it didn't work for me.!!! below is my error log...
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Comment: In spite of ignoring this warning, you should try to fix it out in the proper way.

Comment: Thank you:) Worked in my case .

Answer (score 2):

Try running gradle from command line:

```
gradle clean build --debug
```

And post your log afterwards.

Comment: MarkySmarky, I run the command but I think there is more than 4,5 pages of info I cant paste it here, so I run gradle build --stacktrace. Please check the updated part of the question for log output.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, image file something wrong. Go to (`drawable`) and remove image or replace with new image.This will solve problem.

In addition, you can put method in (`build.gradle`), but This will not solve the problem but good way to catch up what was wrong.

In `build.gradle`, section `android {}`, insert `aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }`.

Answer (score 1):

Just check this link - [Android Studio - mergeDebugResources exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121033/android-studio-mergedebugresources-exception) and [libpng error: Not a PNG file Error Showing In Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366222/libpng-error-not-a-png-file-error-showing-in-android-studio)

You can try this command as well sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 on the console if you are working on a linux machine, then restart android studio and run your project

Comment: It didn't work.Anyway thanks for posting your time. :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was a corrupted PNG file. Go to your `res` folder and try to open every images.

Answer (score 1):

On react native

When you're inside your project directory try using :

> $ cd android && gradlew clean
>
> $ cd .. && react-native run-android

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue checked all the related answer but my problem was not solved.
I added a new folder drawable to add icons in my app. So after deleting that folder my problem was resolved.
Also, clean the Gradle your problem will be resolved.

`cd android && gradlew clean`
 `cd .. && react-native run-android`

Also, there may be some data which is corrupted like images you have added, try to remove those images may it work.

Answer (score 0):

compress the project file and delete prjct. and extract it and open

Answer (score 0):

In my res folder I created a 9PNG file. After deleting this file everthing is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Browse Through Your Project Manifest and Resource Files to see if
   there is an error in the Images you are using. (I was missing the
   roundLauncherIcon).
2. Check if all the images that you are using are
   actually existing.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting this error because the full path to the folder was longer than allowed by Windows. I moved my build to a shallower path and this error went away.

Related question: [Android Studio 2.2 Google play services sync Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595441/android-studio-2-2-google-play-services-sync-error)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error too. But it has fixed now.

The main problem is some Gradle files are corrupted. I have deleted entire .gradle file and run the project again. This time it got worked!.

When I run after deleting .gradle file, it automatically repaired the Gradle files as shown below:

LOG IN DEBUG CONSOLE:

```
This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.

 **Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/annotation/NonNull'
 Example of support library reference: 'android/support/annotation/NonNull'**

√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...

Waiting for RMX1921 to report its views...

Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56754/iCJTNoGKPFA=/ws

Syncing files to device RMX1921...
```

Comment: That is better. I've submitted an edit to format the console output so it's easier to tell it apart from your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have deleted all PNG files in res folder and then I have reinstalled that and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful to someone.

I had the same error and tried the code sample below as well as deleting my .grade, to deleting my .build and .idea which didn't work.

```
aaptOptions {  
    cruncherEnabled = false  
}
```

I later discovered what was causing the error.

If the error wasn't caused by changing an image file extension manually. I suggest to check your strings or array.xml and make sure you aren't using a single quote without having backslash before the single quote.

Error:

```
Côte d'Ivoire
```

Fix:

```
Côte d\'Ivoire
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything above mentioned but couldn't find anything. Then I backed up my code and reverted to last runnable commit, after that i copy/pasted my code back to original piece by piece and added the files again and i found out the problem. I did `<item>Driver's License</item>` which i changed to `<item>Driver\'s License</item>` inside string array in strings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd adroid
./gradlew clean
```

worked for me