# Android Studio 2.2 Google play services sync Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I have update to android studio 2.2

I started a new project and i included

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
```

in my dependencies.

I am getting this Error when im launching the gradle sync.

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file D:\Android\cloned apps\android-vision-master\android-vision-master\visionSamples\barcode-reader\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.4.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png into D:\Android\cloned apps\android-vision-master\android-vision-master\visionSamples\barcode-reader\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file D:\Android\cloned apps\android-vision-master\android-vision-master\visionSamples\barcode-reader\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.4.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png into D:\Android\cloned apps\android-vision-master\android-vision-master\visionSamples\barcode-reader\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 2.132 secs
>   Information:2 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: I updated my machine to AS 2.2 and created a new project. I didn't get any error you cited. Try to move the project to a shorter path and update your Android SDK.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From what I understood, `Failed to crunch file` means studio can't process the file. This error usually occurs when you hit **Maximum File Path Length Limitation**(240 characters) of Windows OS.

I would suggest moving your project into upper directory (like D:\barcode-reader).

Comment: Glad I could help..:)

Comment: thanks it solve the problem by  just renaming current directory but i don't understand why they put limit.

Comment: I think this limit was introduced in DOS days... When you renamed the current directory say from "barcode-reader" to "br" number of character in the file path reduces. In your case, I have to assume,renaming the current directory reduced the path to less than 240 characters..

Comment: Great! Solved my problem, I don't understand why is there still 240 chars limit.

Comment: Seems strange that we still have this limit. Seems like something that should have gone away circa Windows 2000...

Answer (score 25):

The problem is indeed the long file path. However, instead of moving your project, you could change the build directory for your project. This should solve the issue.
In your root build.gradle add:

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    repositories {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be a better solution.

Comment: This definitely seems like a better approach but when building the SDK seems to complain about not finding certain files for its style (specifically values-v23.xml). I'm working on a Cocos2d-x project at the moment and the error I get is:

`Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.`

Comment: Can't edit my own comment...

The solution to my problem was to up the target and compile SDK to version 23 on all of the sub projects. Upping the build tools version to 23.0.2 also helped.

Answer (score 1):

Just reduce your file path length, Reduce to maximum 240 characters.

Answer (score -1):

try by adding like this ..

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0'
```

**And in Android Studio 2.2 it will automatically add the dependence just select it from 'Assistant'** then select service that you want in project and **Connect to Firebase**

[image]

Comment: i didn't work, im still getting the same error above

Comment: what is your gradle version ??

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

Comment: have you added this  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` if not then add

Comment: I did, it's all added here

Comment: I tried it on my other laptop where i didn't yet upgrade, it works fine, just when i updated to 2.2 today , im having this issue

Comment: @user987760 did find any solution..?