# Android Studio : triple selection of png files

Tags: android-studio, imageview

In my new project on android studio I need to insert three .png files .. I pasted the images into the "drawable" folder. I have been careful to name them correctly to avoid possible mistakes caused by special characters in the name...

The problem is that when I start the app, only when my three png files are present in the layout throught ImageView, appear an error saying that "files are crunching". I think that the problem is in "how" I selected the three images by the desktop : Before I paste them into drawable I have selected them all at one time, so I think that the problem can be caused by this triple selection. The mistake can be this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43458892/7973751. And make sure to clear cache and rebuild, please.

OR, it can be happened because the file path length is too long. Please check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42644364/7973751.