# MergeDebugResources not solved although I have made the path short

Tags: java, android

[image]

I have made the path short for my project but still it is showing the error MergeDebugResources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to crunch file - Android studio (app:mergeDebugResources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267005/failed-to-crunch-file-android-studio-appmergedebugresources)