# Nine PNG Crunching Crunsher

Tags: android, nine-patch

Hi I have added below nine patch image in my project, when I do compile a project then Android Studio gives me an error.

> "...Crunching Crunsher ...png failed"

How can I solve this issue. Thanks

[image]

I generated nine patch image from below image

[image]

I have checked all answers which are here [Execution failed for task 'app:mergeDebugResources' Crunching Cruncher....png failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa)

Comment: Okay .Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366222/libpng-error-not-a-png-file-error-showing-in-android-studio

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Not working for me

Comment: Try removing black line on the bottom and right

Answer (score 0):

Try below image it's working ...
[image]

Comment: I want a nine patch png of it

Comment: Download image :- https://www.dropbox.com/s/bn8maaqh71uvxyr/test.9.png?dl=0